# Show matrix A is likely orthogonal if columns and rows have unit norm

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I have an intuitive feeling that an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is likely orthogonal if each column is a unit norm and each row is a unit norm, but I don't know how to rigorously show this.

I've started out by assuming $(A^T)A \neq I$, hoping to show that can never be the case, but I'm not sure how to show this for all cases.

How do I show the matrix to be orthogonal?

Comment: The rows should be orthogonal to each other (the columns too).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what you mean with "unit norm" but consider the 2 by 2 matrix consisting of the entries $1/\sqrt{2}$. Each row and column has unit 2-norm but the matrix is not orthogonal, disproving the hypothesis.

Comment: interesting would be additionally to add condition $\det(A)=1 $ and to see whether there are counterexamples.